# Creating horizontal lines connecting points using QGIS Geometry generator

Tags: qgis, polyline-creation, geometry-generator, geometry-conversion, qgis-expression

I am using the geometry generator to learn how to generate vectors using expressions. Currently, I have a point vector, and I would like to create horizontal lines (shown in red: manually drawn) connecting the points, as illustrated in the image below:

[image: Requires Lines]

I am aware that the `make_line` function allows us to create lines. How should I modify my code to generate a line that passes through these points horizontally?

The condition I intend to use is to connect lines with the same Y coordinates.

```
make_line(collect($geometry, group_by:=y($geometry))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest is probably

```
make_line (array_agg ($geometry, group_by:=$y))
```

Or, extending your version, you can add a [`geometries_to_array()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#geometries-to-array) function: it is [available since QGIS 3.28](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog328/index.html#feature-make-valid-and-geom-to-array-functions), so for older versions use the expression above:

```
make_line( 
    geometries_to_array (
        collect ($geometry, group_by:=$y)
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to extract this generated line in any vector format? or is this only useful for visualization purpose?

Comment: I tried using 'Geometry by expression' but there is error 'Evaluation error: Cannot use aggregate function in this context.'

Comment: Yes, Geoemtry by expression would be the way to do so. Unfortunately, as you realized, it does not work with aggregate functions. Maybe post this as a separate question.